# How to explain funny behavior of call/cc in Racket?

Tags: racket

`combine` must map reduce a list with the binary operator `bin` but must return `exc` if it finds any value that fails the predicate `pred?`, and if it finds any such value it must not perform any calculation on the list.

This is a simple continuation problem.

```
#lang racket

(define (id x)
  x)

(define (const x)
  (lambda (_) x))

(define (combine pred? bin zero exc)
  (call/cc
   (lambda (exit)
     (letrec
         ((f (lambda (xs)
               (if (empty? xs)
                   zero
                   (if (pred? (first xs))
                       (exit exc)
                       (bin (first xs) (f (rest xs))))))))
       f))))

(define product
  (combine zero?
           *
           1
           0))

(product '(1 2 3 0 4))
```

The code almost works, but it has a very subtle error.

It raises the following exception:

```
define-values: assignment disallowed;
 cannot re-define a constant
  constant: product
```

It is easy to make it work. Only a small change is needed:

```
(define (combine pred? bin un zero exc)
  (lambda (ys)
    (call/cc
     (lambda (exit)
       (letrec
           ((f (lambda (xs)
                 (if (empty? xs)
                     zero
                     (if (pred? (first xs))
                         (exit exc)
                         (bin (first xs) (f (rest xs))))))))
         (f ys))))))
```

I see that the problem is that Racket the continuation of define is to define  a function, but can anyone give more details? What syntatic transformations involved, for example?

Answer (score 1):

Think of the order you have to have here:

```
(define product (combine ....))
```

Here you first evaluate `(combine ...)` and the continuation is the rest of the program starting with storing the computed value as the name `product`. Calling the continuation from withing  `f` jumps right back to storing `product` all over again.

By calling `(product '(1 2 3 0 4))` you are redefining `product` since it is the continuation of the program and `call/cc` captures the continuation.

In your second attempt you do a true refactoring of wrapping it in a lambda and call f with the same argument. It's just delaying when the `call/cc` happens and thus what is included in the continuation. In this version the continuation is whatever comes after the `(product ...)` and not the setting pf `product` in `(define product ...)`

Comment: Can this be explained in terms of scheme itself or do we have to look outside the language, in the implementation?

Comment: @Rdgstv `#lang racket` does not follow a standard, but it seems to [be compatible](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_idx_352) with the `#!r6rs`  report: *"Implementation responsibilities: Implementations should detect that the continuation of <expression> is invoked more than once. If the implementation detects this, it must raise an exception with condition type &assertion."*. Racket (the implementation) has support for many of the standard Scheme report languages. I've seen many "scheme" implementations that has `define` and `set!` as the same primitive.

Comment: @Rdgstv As to understand `call/cc`. All `call/cc` does is to expose the continuation as a function. Many Scheme implementations transform you code to CPS anyway, but those who don't does it for `call/cc`. CPS `call/cc` is just `(define (call/cc body c) (body (lambda (value actual-continuation) (c value)) c))`. The special forms like `define` is hard to do in CPS since we don't have the primitive that defines a top level binding from within a function. (`define` inside a function becomes a `letrec` and that isn't what we want)